# Java Unit test for Exception

Tags: junit, powermock

```
public Document query(String uri) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException
{

    final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    Document doc = null;
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(entity.getContent());
    }
    catch (SAXException e)
    {

        LOGGER.error(e);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("parse error" + e);
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
    {

        LOGGER.error(e);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("parameter factor is invalid: " + e);
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {

        LOGGER.error(e);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null entity contetents" + e);
    }

    return doc;
}


 @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testQuery_ParseExceptionThrown() throws Exception
{
    String uri ="some uri";
    EasyMock.expect(httpClient.execute(EasyMock.isA(HttpGet.class))).andReturn(mockResponse);
    EasyMock.expect(mockResponse.getEntity()).andReturn(mockEntity);
    EasyMock.expect(mockEntity.getContent()).andReturn(new ByteArrayInputStream(REPSONSE_EXAMPLE.getBytes()));
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();


    EasyMock.expect(builder.parse(EasyMock.isA(InputStream.class))).andThrow(
            new IllegalArgumentException("expected"));
    EasyMock.replay();
    class.query(uri);

}
```

error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling verify is not allowed in record state
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.verify(MocksControl.java:181)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.verify(EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verify(PowerMock.java:1650)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verifyAll(PowerMock.java:1586)
    at com.amazon.ams.test.AbstractUnitTest.verifyMocks(AbstractUnitTest.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runAfters(MethodRoadie.java:145)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:99)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I keep getting some errors like

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.xml.sax.SAXException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling verify is not allowed in record state
```

There are 3 exceptions I need to write Junit test to get into the exception. Does anyone know how to use powermock or easymock class to write the unit test for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a mock for the `builder` using easymock you can throw Exceptions instead of return values:

```
EasyMock.expect(builder.parse(myContent)).andThrow( myException);
```

Where myException is an Exception  instance you want to throw (created by new MyException(...));

EDIT: example test code:

```
@Test
public void parseThrowsIllegalStateException(){
    //... creating mock factory, builder and entity not shown

    //create new Exception to be thrown
    IllegalStateException expectedException = new IllegalStateException("expected");

    EasyMock.expect(mockBuilder.parse(mockContent).andThrow(expectedException);

    EasyMock.replay(...);

    //exercise your system under test which tries to parse the entity's Content
    //...
}
```

EDIT 2:  now that you posted your actual test code  I think the problem might be these lines:

```
EasyMock.expect(mockEntity.getContent()).andReturn(new ByteArrayInputStream(REPSONSE_EXAMPLE.getBytes()));

...
EasyMock.expect(builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(malformed_XML.getBytes()))).andThrow(new SAXException("expected"));
```

I don't think ByteArrayInputStream overrides equals() so it is using Object.equals().  The ByteArrayInputStreams won't be equal so EasyMock will never throw the Exception

I would change the builder.parse() expectation to:

```
EasyMock.expect(builder.parse(EasyMock.isA(InputStream.class))).andThrow(new SAXException("expected"));
```

Which will throw when parse is called no matter what the inputStream is.

As a side note, your error message the mentioned "calling verify is not allowed in record state" but I don't see any calls to verify() or verifyAll() anywhere.

Comment: cant get this through.. can you be specific?

Comment: still cant get this through for junit test, can you take a look about the code i updated. having this trouble for few days.

Comment: still getting the call verify error.  update the code and paste the error message. I also try mock the DocumentbUilder but still same error. I didn't see verify() also.

Comment: solved. need to mock static for doucmentFactory.class and add prepare class to run.